# Regarding basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

We know that $\{[a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{Q}:a<b\}$ is a basis for a topology which is strictly finer than the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I have also shown that this topology is contained in the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But I couldn't find an example to show that this topology is strictly contained in the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $[\sqrt2,2)$ is open in the lower limit topology but not in this one; why?

Comment: $[\sqrt{2},2)$ is not open in this topology as there does not contain any member in the basis which contain $\sqrt{2}$ and is contained in $[\sqrt{2},2)$.

Comment: @Anupam: You’ve got it. And the same thing happens at every irrational.

Comment: @ B. M. Scott: Thank you Sir!

Comment: @Anupam: You’re welcome!